# Implement 3rd party class in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate a middle east based payment gateway for payments via debit card in a Laravel project for first time. I have used this payment gateway in custom PHP projects in past but facing issues integrating it in a Laravel project.

Basically this payment gateway files consist of a class called **e24PaymentPipe** and a **resource/resource.cgn**. The brief structure of these two files is as follows:

**e24PaymentPipe**

Full class source code: [here](https://github.com/TigerWolf/e24PaymentPipe-php/blob/master/e24PaymentPipe.inc.php)!

```
class e24PaymentPipe {
    var $SUCCESS = 0;
    var $FAILURE = -1;
    var $BUFFER = 2320;
    var $strIDOpen = "<id>";
    var $strPasswordOpen = "<password>";
    ..... some more vars ......

    function e24PaymentPipe() {
        $this->webAddress = "";
        $this->port = "443";
        $this->id = "";
        $this->password = "";
        ... some more vars
    }

    function getWebAddress() {
        return webAddress;
    }

    function setWebAddress($s) {
        $this->webAddress = $s;
    }

    ... sme more functions ...
}
```

**resource/resource.cgn**

This file contains some strings:

```
13d6 acd1 35e2 f54d 2dab 7d9d 63bc 9bb2
6f8f 1fd9 2fc2 aa41 4a8e 873e 98a6 2304
```

**Implementation**

In the page where the Payment button will be displayed, the following code needs to be added:

```
// BENEFIT PAYMENT Code 

require('e24PaymentPipe.inc.php');
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Bahrain');

$accATM = new e24PaymentPipe;
$accATM->resourcePath = 'resource/';
$accATM->alias = 'SECRET_ALIAS_OF_MERCHANT';
$accATM->action = '1';
$accATM->currency = '048';
$accATM->language = 'USA';
$accATM->amt = 'PRICE_HERE';
$accATM->responseURL = '/response.php';
$accATM->errorURL = '/error_page.php';
$accATM->trackId = date('YmdHis');

$TransVal = $accATM->performPaymentInitialization();
$varRawResponse = $accATM->getRawResponse();
$varPaymentId = $accATM->getPaymentId();
$varPaymentPage = $accATM->getPaymentPage();
$varErrorMsg = $accATM->getErrorMsg();
```

**HTML FORM** (that displays button which will take user to Payment Gateways page to complete debit card payments, upon completion user will be redirected back to site)

```
<!-- Benefit Debit Card Payment Button -->
<form action="<?php echo $varPaymentPage; ?>" method="get" class="pull-left" style="margin-left:20px;">
    <input id="PaymentID" name="PaymentID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $varPaymentId; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" value="Debit Card Payment" />
</form>
```

I am new to Laravel, this is one of my first projects. Please help, Thanks.

**EDIT**

By the way, here is GitHub repo for this **e24PaymentPipe** class, you can view full code of this class and its implementation here:

https://github.com/TigerWolf/e24PaymentPipe-php

Hope this could help.

---

@Angel M. here's what I'm doing:

**Controller Function**

```
public function payment() {
    $accATM = new \e24PaymentPipe;

    return View::make('site.payment', compact('accATM'));
}
```

**payment.blade.php**

```
<?php
$accATM->resourcePath = app_path().'/views/site/resource';
$accATM->alias = 'SECRET_ALIAS_HERE';
$accATM->action = '1';
$accATM->currency = '048';
$accATM->language = 'USA';
$accATM->amt = $participant->price;
$accATM->responseURL = '/response.php';
$accATM->errorURL = '/error_page.php';
$accATM->trackId = date('YmdHis');

$accATM->udf2 = 'ud2465665';
$accATM->udf3 = 'ud3231213';
$accATM->udf4 = 'ud4785653';
$accATM->udf5 = 'ud5554788';

$TransVal = $accATM->performPaymentInitialization();
$varRawResponse = $accATM->getRawResponse();
$varPaymentId = $accATM->getPaymentId();
$varPaymentPage = $accATM->getPaymentPage();
$varErrorMsg = $accATM->getErrorMsg();

?>

!-- Benefit Debit Card Payment -->
<form action="<?php echo $varPaymentPage; ?>" method="get" class="pull-left" style="margin-left:20px;">
    <input id="PaymentID" name="PaymentID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $varPaymentId; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" value="Debit Card Payment" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create e24PaymentPipe in your App root directory
Open composer.json

```
 "classmap": [
     "database",
     "app/e24PaymentPipe" <-- add this line to classmap
  ],
```

run composer dump-autoload; 
in your controller

```
public function __construct(){
    $e24payment = new \e24PaymentPipe;  
}
```

Comment: Tried that, and then added the implementation code and form to my payment page view like how I've shown in my original post. Getting this error when I open the page:  **Creating default object from empty value (View: payment.blade.php)**

Answer (score 0):

I would add the payment class in special folder like payments inside app folder, or whatever you would prefer.

Then would add the path in composer to autoload section:

```
   "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
      ... etc..
        "app/payments"
    ],
```

and then run

composer dump-autoload, so the file would be loaded
and then add form and the rest of the code into the appropriate class/views.

in the controller when you will manage the payment (I don't know which one you will use)

inside a method add:
$payment = new e24PaymentPipe;

```
public function payment()
{
  $accATM = new e24PaymentPipe;
    $accATM->resourcePath = 'resource/';
    $accATM->alias = 'SECRET_ALIAS_OF_MERCHANT';
    $accATM->action = '1';
    $accATM->currency = '048';
    $accATM->language = 'USA';
    $accATM->amt = 'PRICE_HERE';
    $accATM->responseURL = '/response.php';
    $accATM->errorURL = '/error_page.php';
    $accATM->trackId = date('YmdHis');

    $TransVal = $accATM->performPaymentInitialization();
    $varRawResponse = $accATM->getRawResponse();
    $varPaymentId = $accATM->getPaymentId();
    $varPaymentPage = $accATM->getPaymentPage();
    $varErrorMsg = $accATM->getErrorMsg();

  return View::make('myfolder/payment')->with(... here you will list array of data you will send to the view...);
}
```

where **myfolder/payment** will be myfolder/payment.blade.php file

EDIT:
try to send:

```
View::make('site.payment')->with('accATM',$accATM);
```

and in view you should use something like:

check in view, if data were sent:

```
@if($accATM) ...
```

Comment: What about the rest of the code and form that needs to be added into appropriate view file? Talking about implementation part of my original post.

Comment: @Jazzbot I have updated - but this is more kind of draft, how you can use it, you'll need to add appropriate data ... I just made copy/paste from your code

Comment: Ok, what I did was: added `$accATM = new e24PaymentPipe;` in my controller function and then did `return View::make('site.payment', compact('accATM'));` wrote rest of the code inside **site/payment.blade.php** but its saying **Trying to get property of non-object (View: payment.blade.php)**

Comment: what do you have in payment.blade.php?

Comment: I've updated my original post and added what I'm doing in my controller function and view

Comment: I've fixed the error, now the payment button is displaying. But the values of `$accATM->getPaymentPage()` and `$accATM->getPaymentId()` are empty, these two things are required for this gateway to work.

Comment: please add all the $accATM part to the controller. try to debug dd($accATM) in controller before sending to the view. So you'll see what is wrong

Comment: Did all that already, when I `dd($accATM)` it shows all the variables define in the class. But when I do `dd($accATM->getPaymentId())` or `dd($accATM->getPaymentPage())` it shows empty values.

Comment: so seems you should check those two methods

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a custom service provider like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class YourServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
        $this->app->bind('YOUR_CUSTOM_CLASS_NAMESPACE_PATH');
    }
}
```

Then register your service provider in your config/app.php file

```
YOUR_SERVICE_PROVIDER_NAMESPACE_YOU_CREATED::class,
```

Then in anywhere you can use your YOUR_CUSTOM_CLASS like it,

```
$class = new YOUR_CUSTOM_CLASS();//use use to import the class namespace path
```

Comment: Where should I create this custom service provider? Sorry for this noob question.. :(

Comment: You can create your service providers anywhere but the best practice is to create it inside **`/app/Providers/`** but you have to give correct namespace. Your namespace will be **`namespace App\Providers;`** and when registering your file to **`config/app.php`** register like this **`App\Providers\CUSTOM_SERVICE_PROVIDER::class`**